# How To Set Total1 And Total2 Value Into Label When User Scrolls on Both Segment Of picker View (Dynamically)?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if component == 0 {
        lbl1.text = pdata[0][row]
        lbl1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        img1.image = UIImage(named : pdata[0][row])
        price1.text = priceData[row]
        total1 = Int(priceData[row]) ?? 0

        }

 else if component == 1 {
        lbl2.text = pdata[1][row]
        lbl2.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        img2.image = UIImage(named : imgdata[row])
        price2.text = PriceData2[row]
        total2 = Int(PriceData2[row]) ?? 0

    }

   TotalPrice.text = String(total1! + total2!)



}
```

When user scroll on 1 `Segment` then total becomes `nil` and `app` crashes how can I store both total 1 and total 2 variable to show sum of `price` to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use coalescing operator to prevent force unwrap:

```
TotalPrice.text = String((total1 ?? 0) + (total2 ?? 0))
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator

Comment: If User Select only first component than how to show the price or user select only 2 component and third case if user select both component ?

Comment: You can use this code: TotalPrice.text = String((total1 ?? 0) + (total2 ?? 0)), I updated my answer

Comment: Thanx It Works  :-)

Comment: @Amey Great, please accept my answer if it has helped you :)